# RUNNABLE Thread.State but in Object.wait()

Tags: java, multithreading

I have extracted a JStack of my container process and got the threads running there with the following distribution grouped by `Thread.state`:

```
count    thread state
   67    RUNNABLE
    1    TIMED_WAITING (on object monitor)
    8    TIMED_WAITING (parking)
    4    TIMED_WAITING (sleeping)
    3    WAITING (on object monitor)
   17    WAITING (parking)
```

For the runnable threads I have the following description:

```
"http-bio-8080-exec-55" daemon prio=10 tid=0x000000002cbab300 nid=0x642b in Object.wait() [0x00002ab37ad11000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at com.mysema.query.jpa.impl.JPAQuery.<init>(JPAQuery.java:44)
    at net.mbppcb.cube.repository.TransactionDaoImpl.findByBusinessId(TransactionDaoImpl.java:73)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor76.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:155)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
    ...
```

The number of threads in RUNNABLE state as shown above raises with the time and it seems to be hanging. If they suppose to be blocked, shouldn't they be on state BLOCKED? Or should they be on WAITING state? Is strange to have RUNNABLE threads but in Object.wait() isn't it?

**Update 1**

I can see in the documentation:

> A thread in the runnable state is executing in the Java virtual
>   machine but it may be waiting for other resources from the operating
>   system such as processor.

How can I figure out what is the thread waiting for?

Comment: Threads in `Object.wait()` should have `Thread.State.WAITING`, not `BLOCKED`. That said, I don't know why it would be `RUNNABLE`.

Comment: You are right, my mistake. But could this odd state be related to my JVM version and OS version? Maybe kind of odd bug with combination of both or so?

Comment: What is the rest of the stack trace of the threads in Object.wait()?

Comment: @DennisW the fact that the thread is in a call to `o.wait()` is not as tightly coupled to its state as you imagine.  When the event is signalled, the state of the thread will change from `WAITING` to `RUNNABLE`, but the thread still will be in the `o.wait()` call.  Then it will go through other state changes:  It will eventually get to run, and then it may be blocked again while trying to re-acquire the lock, and then it will become `RUNNABLE` a second time, and finally, it will get to run a second time, and it will return from the call.

Comment: @KristofferE: just added additional information regarding stacktrace

Comment: What version of mysema are you using?

Answer (score 28):

This seems like a  [class initialization deadlock](http://ternarysearch.blogspot.ru/2013/07/static-initialization-deadlock.html).

`JPAQuery` constructor is waiting for the initialization of a dependent class, probably `JPAProvider`:

```
    public JPAQuery(EntityManager em) {
        super(em, JPAProvider.getTemplates(em), new DefaultQueryMetadata());
    }
```

Such deadlocks may be caused by a [typical bug](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8037567) when a subclass is referenced from a static initializer. If you share the details of other thread stacks, we'll likely find out which thread holds the class lock.

Why is the thread in `RUNNABLE` state then?

Well, it's a confusion inside HotSpot JVM. The class initialization procedure is implemented in VM runtime, not in Java land, and the class lock is grabbed natively. Seems to be a reason why a thread state has not been changed, but I guess this behavior should be fixed in JVM as well.

Comment: the problem I had with mysema is exactly this (class initialization deadlock), this is the ticket opened on mysema: https://github.com/querydsl/querydsl/issues/1237https://github.com/querydsl/querydsl/issues/1237

Comment: Thanks for this! I have been bugged by seeing RUNNABLE threads in Object.wait() on several occassions now. I just verified what you are describing is actually what was happening.

Answer (score 4):

The [Oracle Thread.State documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.State.html) specifies that a thread in the blocked state is waiting for a monitor lock to enter a synchronized block/method or reenter a synchronized block/method after calling.
It looks like none of the threads in blocking mode.

Answer (score 1):

If all the Runnable threads are apparently blocked in database operations, I would suggest using database monitoring/diagnostic tools to explore the reason. After that, possibly investigating your database code to find problems such as uncommitted transactions, mishandled exceptions leading to unclosed resources.

Java thread dumps have probably given you all the information they can at this point - a pointer for where to start looking next.

Comment: Its a valid point, although, I would expect calls to the DB driver in the call stack if it was blocked by a query right? The strange thing here is that this occurs on `JPAQuery.<init>`, let me know your thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

> "The number of threads in RUNNABLE state as shown above raises with
>   the time and it seems to be hanging."

The number of RUNNABLES would rise depending upon the number of threads executing the method "com.mysema.query.jpa.impl.JPAQuery." at the time this thread dump was taken. This method is actually the constructor of JPAQuery class - denoted by *"init"*. You would probably need to investigate the code in the constructor and the subsequent calls to the JPA implementation.

Comment: when I commented it raises with the time, it was meant that the thread will stops in a given point (constructor of JPAQuery) and will not be returned to the pool, if I take more thread dumps that thread will be at the same point

Answer (score 0):

The `Object.wait()` merely calls `Object.wait(0)` (zero for no timeout).
The implementation of `Object.wait(long)` is:

```
public final native void wait(long timeout) throws InterruptedException;
```

All threads that are in a native frame are `RUNNABLE`, as the JVM does not know (does not "manage", hence it is a "native" frame) the state of the call.